# string comparisons in php (to create a sql query)

Tags: php, sql, string, logic

I'd like to know how I check whether one or more of the elements (numbers in this case) in a string, eg. '1,2,3,5' are in another ,eg. '3,4,5,6'

3 and 5 are common elements to each string in that example.

In this case it is to create a SQL query based on the string comparisons.
One column value  in a db contains one number string, and needs to be compared to another. I need results that match values of each string.

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM db
        WHERE comparisonString IN (".$idsString.")
        ")->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But its not quite working... it could be a lateral or syntactic answer.

MORE SPECIFICALLY, I am only getting a result when the FIRST element in the comaprisonString matches the other string elements.

Ideally the solution will look something like this:

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM db
        WHERE ELEMENTS IN comparisonString IN (".$idsString.")
        ")->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

"ELEMENTS IN" is made up syntax, but that's the sort of thing I'm after

Comment: BTW I've thought about looping iterations of on array over another, but I need to create one set of results for the SQL query

Comment: I've also considered in_array() but I don't know how to build that into the query

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it smells like a bad schema design. Don't store delimited strings of values in your database. Normalize your data by creating a many-to-many table. It will pay off big time enabling you to normally maintain and query your data.

In the meantime if you're using MySQL and assuming that your table looks something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  column_name varchar(128)
);
```

and let's say you have sample data

```
| ID | COLUMN_NAME |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |     3,4,5,6 |
|  2 |      4,6,22 |
|  3 |      7,5,11 |
|  4 |    9,12,1,3 |
|  5 |     8,32,16 |
```

and you want to select all rows where `column_name` contains one or more values from a list `1,2,3,5` you can do either

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, column_name) > 0
    OR FIND_IN_SET(2, column_name) > 0
    OR FIND_IN_SET(3, column_name) > 0
    OR FIND_IN_SET(5, column_name) > 0
```

or

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT id 
    FROM table1 t JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 1 value UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
  ) s
      ON FIND_IN_SET(s.value, t.column_name) > 0
   GROUP BY id
) q
    ON t.id = q.id
```

Output (in both cases):

```
| ID | COLUMN_NAME |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |     3,4,5,6 |
|  3 |      7,5,11 |
|  4 |    9,12,1,3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b362e/3)** demo

Comment: Thanks @peterm , I'm considering the schema for sure. But the string db entry points to another table and the string it is compared to is based on user input in the UI. Hence I cannot predict how many elements are in either string.

Comment: I think the thing missing from my current code is that the elements in the "WHERE comparisonString" part aren't interated over unlike in the "IN (".$idsString.")" part, where they are.